# Writing SOAP XML response to file

Tags: java, xml, web-services, soap

I am trying to access a SOAP service to get data from a URL. I have configured the SOAP service successfully. 
I am running the following methods for getting response from the SOAP service

```
soapResponse = soapConnection.call(SoapMsg, endPoint);
soapResponse.writeTo(fileName);
```

But I get OutOfMemory Exception while getting the response

```
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
    at java.util.Arrays.copyOf(Arrays.java:3236) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
    at java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream.grow(ByteArrayOutputStream.java:118) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
    at java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream.ensureCapacity(ByteArrayOutputStream.java:93) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
    at java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream.write(ByteArrayOutputStream.java:153) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
    at com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.client.p2p.HttpSOAPConnection.readFully(HttpSOAPConnection.java:553) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
    at com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.client.p2p.HttpSOAPConnection.post(HttpSOAPConnection.java:318) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
    at com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.client.p2p.HttpSOAPConnection.call(HttpSOAPConnection.java:145) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
```

Hence I want to write to file by breaking the response into smaller chunks before the whole response is retrieved. Any idea how to configure it in this manner?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

you might have to increase heap memory
[Increase heap size in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1565388/increase-heap-size-in-java)

or try streaming the response.

connection.call(SoapMsg, endPoint).writeTo( new FileOutputStream( new File(fileName) ) );

Not sure if this one will work thought, as I usually work with rest API's.

Perhaps you could try reducing the amount of data returned by updating the SoapMsg. Maybe pagination is an option.